# Zend Framework: Allowing Meta Properties for the HTML5 Doctype (Facebook Open Graph)

Tags: html, zend-framework, facebook-opengraph, zend-view, rdfa

I am using the `HTML5` doctype in my Zend Framework application. If I use `XHTML1_RDFA` as my doctype, the `headMeta` view helper allows me to use the `appendProperty()` function. I know that meta properties are not valid in HTML5, but I want to do it anyway. How do I override the behavior so that I can add these meta tags?

I've found these related posts on SO, but they don't answer this specific question:

- [Zend framework: Meta property integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457467/zend-framework-meta-property-integration)
- [HTML5 and RDFa support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177700/html5-and-rdfa-support)
- [Opengraph validation for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501189/opengraph-validation-for-html5)

Comment: Why was the `xhtml1-rdfa` tag removed? It seems like it's a valid tag. Is there a different tag I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended the HeadMeta view helper to allow them. It validates at http://validator.w3.org/ too.

```
class My_View_Helper_HeadMeta extends Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta
{
    /**
     * Determine if item is valid
     *
     * @param  mixed $item
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isValid($item)
    {
        if ((!$item instanceof stdClass)
            || !isset($item->type)
            || !isset($item->modifiers))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($item->content)
        && (! $this->view->doctype()->isHtml5()
        || (! $this->view->doctype()->isHtml5() && $item->type !== 'charset'))) {
            return false;
        }

        // <meta property= ... /> is only supported with doctype RDFa
        if (!$this->view->doctype()->isRdfa()
            && !$this->view->doctype()->isHtml5()
            && $item->type === 'property') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```